# Partitions of n into k parts with restrictions

Tags: algorithm, partitioning

I need an algorithm that produces a partition of the number `n` into `k` parts with the added restrictions that each element of the partition must be between `a` and `b`. Ideally, all possible partitions satisfying the restrictions should be equally likely. Partitions are considered the same if they have the same elements in different order.

For example, with `n=10`, `k=3`, `a=2`, `b=4` one has only `{4,4,2}` and `{4,3,3}` as possible outcomes.

Is there a standard algorithm for such a problem? One can assume that at least one partition satisfying the restrictions always exists.

Comment: I answered a very similar question recently, with an algorithm that computes the conditional probabilities and samples accordingly: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41871179/2144669

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this as a recursive algorithm. Basically, the recurrence is like this:

- if `k == 1` and `a <= n <= b`, then the only partition is `[n]`, otherwise none
- otherwise, combine all the elements `x` from `a` to `b` with all the partitions for `n-x`, `k-1`
- to prevent duplicates, also substitute the lower bound `a` with `x`

Here's some Python (aka executable pseudo-code):

```
def partitions(n, k, a, b):
    if k == 1 and a <= n <= b:
        yield [n]
    elif n > 0 and k > 0:
        for x in range(a, b+1):
            for p in partitions(n-x, k-1, x, b):
                yield [x] + p

print(list(partitions(10, 3, 2, 4)))
# [[2, 4, 4], [3, 3, 4]]
```

This could be further improved by checking `(k-1)*a` and `(k-1)*b` for the lower and upper bounds for the remaining elements, respectively, and restricting the range for `x` accordingly:

```
        min_x = max(a, n - (k-1) * b)
        max_x = min(b, n - (k-1) * a)
        for x in range(min_x, max_x+1):
```

For `partitions(110, 12, 3, 12)` with 3,157 solutions, this reduces the number of recursive calls from 638,679 down to 24,135.

Comment: Hm, guess I missed the part that you want a single, random partition, and not the entire list... well, you could still generate them all and then pick one randomly. This would also guarantee that each legal permutation is equally likely.

Answer (score 1):

If `k` and `b - a` are not too big you can try a randomized depth-first search:

```
import random

def restricted_partition_rec(n, k, min, max):
    if k <= 0 or n < min:
        return []
    ps = list(range(min, max + 1))
    random.shuffle(ps)
    for p in ps:
        if p > n:
            continue
        elif p < n:
            subp = restricted_partition(n - p, k - 1, min, max)
            if subp:
                return [p] + subp
        elif k == 1:
            return [p]
    return []

def restricted_partition(n, k, min, max):
    return sorted(restricted_partition_rec(n, k, min, max), reverse=True)

print(restricted_partition(10, 3, 2, 4))
>>>
[4, 4, 2]
```

Although I'm not sure if all the partitions have exactly the same probability in this case.

Comment: The values I am interested are n from 38 to 110, k from 6 to 12, a=3, b=12

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sampling algorithm that uses conditional probability.

```
import collections
import random

countmemo = {}


def count(n, k, a, b):
    assert n >= 0
    assert k >= 0
    assert a >= 0
    assert b >= 0
    if k == 0:
        return 1 if n == 0 else 0
    key = (n, k, a, b)
    if key not in countmemo:
        countmemo[key] = sum(
            count(n - c, k - 1, a, c) for c in range(a, min(n, b) + 1))
    return countmemo[key]


def sample(n, k, a, b):
    partition = []
    x = random.randrange(count(n, k, a, b))
    while k > 0:
        for c in range(a, min(n, b) + 1):
            y = count(n - c, k - 1, a, c)
            if x < y:
                partition.append(c)
                n -= c
                k -= 1
                b = c
                break
            x -= y
        else:
            assert False
    return partition


def test():
    print(collections.Counter(
        tuple(sample(20, 6, 2, 5)) for i in range(10000)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```